# I centered my contact form but now it centered everything on my website

Tags: html, css

I ran into a new problem when I centered my contact form. when  you access  my website everything looks fine but after you login everything is centered which made some things go off the page is there a way to fix so just my contact form is centered and not everything else?

https://jsbin.com/piruiukepo/edit?html,css,output

[image: what happened after I centered the contact form]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the margin of your table auto, but without seeing your code it is difficult to answer.